# Instruments shows (-) Negative value for Live Bytes? I'm confused

Tags: xcode-instruments

I Profile my Xcode app using Allocations from Instruments and everything looks fine as far as *All Allocations* Live Bytes is sitting right around 7 MB. I execute a routine and the Live Bytes jumps (or declines?) to - 6 GB? Yes that's GB and it's negative?
Xcode 4.6.2
Instruments 4.6